# Elements blocking div I'm trying to hover on?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Absolutely stumped here...

I have a dynamically generated list of divs. It goes through each of those divs and applies an event listen on hover. Inside each of those divs is some text, a H1, some body copy and a link. Unfortunately the trigger only fires if I hover on a bit of 'blank space' in the div where there's no text.

I've tried pointer-events:none which does fix the issue but doesn't solve an issue where I have a link. Essentially I just want the whole div to respond when hovered. I swear I've done this before?!

Here's a video demonstrating: [Video Recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRaJS.jpg)

Here's how my JS is set up (the projectsText is getting each project element)

```
    projectsText.forEach(project => {
      project.classList.remove("active")
    })
    event.target.classList.add("active")
  }

  const changeWorkImage = (event) => {
    projects.forEach(image => {
      if (image.id === event.target.id) {
        workImage.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + image.heroImage + ")"
      } else {
        return
      }
    })
  }

  projectsText.forEach(project => {
    project.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
      changeWorkImage(event)
      changeActive(event)
    })
  })
```

And how my component is structured

```
    <div className="project" id={id}>
      <p className="company">{company}</p>
      <h2 className="title">{title}</h2>
      <LearnMore url={url} />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mouseover` event goes to one, and only one, event handler at a time. It gives priority starting with the innermost child (nested/z-index). If you move the cursor from a parent ("project") to one of its children ("title"), then the parent loses the focus of the mouseover event.

There is a similar event, `mouseenter` which *ignore* transitions within an element. In other words, it doesn't pay attention when you move the mouse over children elements, so it in effect works from the outside in. This may work better in your case. (The converse, `mouseleave`, can be used to detect when the mouse has left.)

Comment: you are INCREDIBLE. i've spent hours on this haha and I knew there was an easy way I fixed it last time.... that easy way being mouseenter.

thank you thank you thank you

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Please mark the answer as 'accepted' with the checkmark icon so that others view it as resolved.